# How do I get texlive to work? (Ubuntu)

Tags: texlive, ubuntu

I am working on Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
I want to work with TEXstudio.

When trying to build my pdf I get error messages like:
`File 'biblatex.sty' not found. \addbibresource`
or
`File 'blindtext.sty' not found.`

As far as I understand, I do not have these packages installed. I thought, that that's what I need texlive for in the first place. I looked with `apt list --installed` if both are installed and got:

texlive-base,
texlive-binaries,
texlive-fonts-recommended,
texlive-latex-base,
texlive-latex-extra,
texlive-latex-recommended,
texlive-pictures,
texlive-plain-generic,
texstudio-doc,
texstudio-l10n,
texstudio/focal

Do I need more for it to work?
How do I install singular packages?
I am close to crying, appreciate any help!

Comment: could it rely on the PATH variable? In this tutorial: [link](https://fahim-sikder.github.io/post/installing-texlive-latest-ubuntu/) it says, that I have to edit my bashrc file. I did that, but I am very unsure if I have done that correctly. Could that be where my errors come from?

Comment: First of exactly what TeXLive have you installed? It seems to be the one that comes with Ubuntu? Then you don't need to mess with PATH etc, but instead realise that Ubuntu have split up TeXLive into many Ununtu packages (not comparable to LaTeX backages).  You need to know which `texlive-` package you are missing. You can either install `texlive-all` which installs all. Or install the `apt-file` tool, then run `sudo apt-file update` and after that use it to ask Ubuntu which Ubuntu package provides `biblatex.sty` via `apt-file search biblatex.sty`, and then you just install that Unbutu package

Comment: It is **very** confusing to users that Ubuntu split TeXLive up this way, but they have their reasons.

Comment: It might be `texlive-bibtex-extra`

Comment: Thats good to know. I will install texlive-full, that's what u meant right? If it's finished, I'll give an update. thanks already

Comment: Yes, but that will install a lot of stuff you'll never use (that is why Debian/Ubuntu make so many packages), but it should solve your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As there are two ways to install TeXLive on Linux, it is important to know what exactly you installed. Since you mentioned

```
texlive-base, texlive-binaries, texlive-fonts-recommended, texlive-latex-base, texlive-latex-extra, texlive-latex-recommended, texlive-pictures, texlive-plain-generic
```

I will assume you're using TeXLive from Debian/Ubuntu.

This TeXLive is split into selveral Ubuntu packages (not related to LaTeX packages), and you thus need to know exactly which of these `texlive-` packages you need or you can install them all by installing `texlive-all` via `apt-get`.

If you want to keep it minimal, here is a tip:

Install `apt-file` via

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
```

then you can look up `biblatex.sty` via

```
apt-file search biblatex.sty
```

and then install the appropriate `texlive-` file from the answer.

Unless they changed the name `biblatex.sty` is in `texlive-bibtex-extra`

Comment: thank you! sudo apt install texlive-full did the thing. I have enough space to have the whole thing, but thanks for the detailed help

Answer (score -1):

There are two general ways: (1) install TeX Live base via `texlive`; (2) install TeX Live full via `texlive-full`. The latter is *massive* at on the order of 10 GB on disk. Hence, I recommend the former via the `texlive` metapackage:

```bash
sudo apt-get install texlive
```

This installs the following packages:

```
dvisvgm fonts-lmodern fonts-texgyre libptexenc1 libteckit0 libtexlua53 libtexluajit2 libzzip-0-13 lmodern t1utils tex-common tex-gyre texlive texlive-base texlive-binaries texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-latex-base texlive-latex-recommended tipa
```

It works just fine. The `texlive-full` metapackage installs fonts for pretty much every language in the world and then some, hence its massive size. An alternative approach would be simply to install that and delete all of the optional fonts it installs or to create your own `texlive-complete` metapackage.

**RECOMMENDATION**: you are better off using [Typst](https://github.com/typst/typst).